# Writing a notification program using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

In trying to learn the Python-tweepy api, I put together a little bit of code that tells me if there has been any new tweets within the most recent ~10 second interval (of course, in practice it is more than 10 seconds because code aside from `sleep(10)` also takes some time to run):

```
from getApi import getApi
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

api = getApi()
top = api.home_timeline()[0].id

while True:
    l = api.home_timeline()
    if top != l[0].id:
        top = l[0].id
        print 'New tweet recognized by Python at: %s' % str(datetime.now())
    sleep(10)
```

getApi is just a few lines of Python I wrote to manage OAuth using tweepy. The getApi method returns the tweepy api, with my account authenticated.

It seems very inefficient that I would have to ask twitter again and again whether there are any new tweets. Is this how it is normally done? If not, what would be the 'canonical' way to do it?

I would have imagined that there would be some code like:

```
api.set_home_timeline_handler(tweetHandler)
```

and tweetHandler would be called whenever there is a new tweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the way the twitter API works - you have ask every time you want to know about stuff on twitter. But beware of rate limiting `https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting` every 10 sec is above the max.

Alternatively there is streaming api: `https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods` that works like you imagined, but it is for bigger tasks than checking your timeline.

Comment: This was answered a while ago. Has there been any movement on the twitter API since?